# Command line - call class from jar which is in war

Tags: java

I have a .war file. Inside this .war file I have WEB-INF folder. Inside WEB-INF I have a lib folder and inside this lib folder I have a .jar file. Inside this jar I have a class with main method. I need to call this method. Can I do this from command line? I don't have an option of deplying war file, so I need a command which will access my class with main method through the war file.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is to go to the location where your jar file  is located from command prompt and type `java youpackagename.yourclassname` .for eg `java net.grinder.Grinder`

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the jar in the `war` package might be difficult. Due to the fact that `war` packaging is intended for deployment on a Java Web server, the `war` packaging is obsolete and not handy for you usecase. Unzip the `war` archive and run the contained `jar` archive after unpacking like you'd run any other `jar` archive with `java -jar /path/to/archive.jar` (you'll find a ton of examples on this page).